# Set range for filter

Tags: excel, vba

I have macro which copy filtered rows (filter in column E, >0) from one sheet (ws1) to another (ws2).

I cannot find why I have error when trying to set up filter in source (ws1) in line 2. I assume this might be a reason of my problem, because macro copy all lines including title of each column (line with filter).
Maybe issue is with copy function? Now I'm not sure. Because of that I have always delete one row after copy.

```
Set rngToCopy = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

Source file: [DropBox](https://www.dropbox.com/l/scl/AABN2_YONHbhz7gcLZ_-qtHsBHZoekD0TrU)

Full code:

```
Sub COPY_SA()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range, rngToCopy As Range
Dim lastrow As Long
Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SA")
Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("JC_input")

With ws1

    'assumung that data stored in column C:E, Sheet1
    lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    'can not make range from row 3 ???
    Set rng = .Range("C1:F" & lastrow)

    .AutoFilterMode = False
    With rng
        'apply filter with criteria in column 3 of range C:E
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">0"
        On Error Resume Next
        'get only visible rows
        Set rngToCopy = .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'copy range
    If Not rngToCopy Is Nothing Then rngToCopy.Range("A:D").Copy
    'paste from row 3
    ws2.Range("A3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues
    'delete no needed row, because of filter from row 2 in ws1
    ws2.Rows(3).Delete

    End With

Application.CutCopyMode = False
  If Not ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then
    ws1.Range("2:2").AutoFilter
    End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would do it:

```
Option Explicit
Sub COPY_SA()

    Dim ws1 As Worksheet: Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("SA")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("JC_input")

    Dim lastrow As Long

    With ws2

        'assumung that data stored in column C:E, Sheet1
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row

        If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False

        .Range("C2:F" & lastrow).AutoFilter 3, ">0" 'change the 5 if you don't want to filter by column E

        'Calculate again the last row to check if there is something to copy
        lastrow = .Cells(2, "C").End(xlDown).Row

        Dim rngToCopy  As Range

        If lastrow > 2 Then 'assuming your headers are on row 2, change this if not
            Set rngToCopy = .Range("C3:F" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 'copy visible data
            With ws1
                lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                .Range("A3:D" & lastrow).ClearContents
                rngToCopy.Copy
                .Range("A3").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .Rows(lastrow + 1 & ":" & ws1.Rows.Count).ClearContents 'this will clear your previous data on all columns
            End With
            .Range("E2").AutoFilter
            Application.CutCopyMode = False
        End If

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Do not works in 100%. Columns C and D from ws1 are paste in C and in ws2. Istead CDEF from ws1 in ABCD ws2. BTW. If I want to add ws2.Range("A3:D999").ClearContents before paste?

Comment: Also notice that filter is in row 1 instead of 2. Now is `.UsedRange.AutoFilter 5, ">0"` instead of `.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">0"`?

Comment: @Pawel as for your first comment try my edit. For your second comment... does it change anything? Is copying what is needed? or the filter won't work?

Comment: For second. It is working but do not looks good. First row got descriptions and buttons.

Comment: For the first. Error: "Duplicate declaration in current scope" for line "Dim rngToCopy  As Range". Question about `ws2.Rows(lastrow + 1 & ":" & ws2.Rows.Count).Delete`. Will this delete or clear rows? I'm asking because, for example declaration `=JC_input!C3` used in another sheet will occur with #REF! error after row disappear.

Comment: I added source file.

Comment: @Pawel yes. that will delete the rows, you can change it to `ClearContents`. Do you mind if I try your file later on? It's giving me an error to access the dropbox, must be the company proxy. Once I can take a peek to your file I'll edit my answer to fit your needs.

Comment: No problem. Im happy that anyone have time to help me  :)

Comment: @Pawel I've tweaked the code with the workbook and now works fine. Thought you were using `ws1` as source and it was `ws2`sorted that.